# html/jquery multiple step form - go to next step depending on which radio button was selected

Tags: jquery, forms

I'm new to jquery and need help with a form, is a single form broken in multiple steps (7). So in the first step (see code below) I have 5 radio buttons: school, friends, home , health, and activity. What I'm trying to achieve is that if a user selects radio button school and clicks the "next" button it will show a div containing questions related to school, if it chooses friends it will show a div with friends related questions, and so on... those subject specific divs are hidden on document load.

Please be nice, newbie here. Any help on this will be greatly appreciated  :)

```
<div class="form">
    <h2>What interests you? (select one)</h2>

    <label class="val" style="width:250px;color:red;">Please select one</label><br> 
    <input type="radio" id="school" name="path" value="school" /> School <br>    
    <input type="radio" id="home" name="path" value="home" /> Home <br>         
    <input type="radio" id="friends" name="path" value="friends" /> Friends <br>           
    <input type="radio" id="activities" name="path" value="activities" /> Activities <br>
    <input type="radio" id="health" name="path" value="health" /> Health <br>
 </div>
 <div class="clear"></div><!-- /clearfix -->
 <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit_first" id="submit_first" value="">Next</button>
 </div>     
 <!-- clearfix --><div class="clear"></div><!-- /clearfix -->
 <div id="step1-1"></div>
 <div id="step1-2"></div>
 <div id="step1-3"></div>
 <div id="step1-4"></div>
 <div id="step1-5"></div>
```

Comment: Probably don't want it to be a submit button, if it's in a form, since that will trigger a post every time it's clicked and it sounds like the button is just a trigger to show different sections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this on click of simple button

```
var val = $('input:radio[name=path]:checked').val();

switch (val )
{
case 'school':
  $('#step1-1').show();
  break;
case 'home':
  $('#step1-2').show();
  break;
case 'friends':
  $('#step1-3').show();
  break;
case 'activities':
 $('#step1-4').show();
  break;
case 'health':
  $('#step1-5').show();
  break;
default:

}
```

Comment: This did it! I just added a bit to the effects. Demo here http://jsfiddle.net/codersky/Cxfgj/ Thanks Farhan!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the document is loaded and you question divs are hidden you could do:

```
$('div.form button').click( function() {
    var value = $('div.form input').val();
    switch (value) {
        case 'school':
            $('#step1-1').show();
        break;
        case 'home':
            $('#step1-2').show();
         break;
        case 'friends':
            $('#step1-3').show();
         break;
        case 'activities':
            $('#step1-4').show();
        break;
        case 'health':
            $('#step1-5').show();
        break;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! this is similar to the solution Farhan provided

Answer (score 0):

I took some liberties here with your markup and guessed your intent with some assumptions.

Jump to this fiddle to see how it works: http://jsfiddle.net/rRmRY/

- Made your `step1-X` elements steps in the process.
- assumed a form of some type for each choice in the step - I used school for an example
- gave the form some internal smartness
- made the button NOT be a submit button
- made the radio label clickable by making them labels not just text for each one
- put a "previous" button on the next form (school form)

Simply choose "school" radio button, then click your "Next" button to see the empty school form in the next step.  I leave it up to you to put what you want in there and to add more forms etc.  The code should be generic IF you copy the previous form as a start.

Revised markup:(incomplete, for you to finish)

```
<div id="step0" class="steps" data-nextstep="step1-1">
    <div class="form"><span class="action">none</span>
         <h2>What interests you? (select one)</h2>
        <label class="val">Please select one</label>
        <label for="school">
            <input type="radio" id="school" name="path" value="school" />School</label>
        <label for="home">
            <input type="radio" id="home" name="path" value="home" />Home</label>
        <label for="home">
            <input type="radio" id="friends" name="path" value="friends" />Friends</label>
        <label for="activities">
            <input type="radio" id="activities" name="path" value="activities" />Activities</label>
        <label for="health">
            <input type="radio" id="health" name="path" value="health" />Health</label>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary formNext" type="button" name="submit_first" id="submit_first" value="">Next</button>
</div>
<div id="step1-1" class="steps" data-nextstep="step1-2">Step 1
    <div class="form school">school
        <button class="previous">Previous Form</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="step1-2" class="steps"></div>
<div id="step1-3" class="steps"></div>
<div id="step1-4" class="steps"></div>
<div id="step1-5" class="steps"></div>
```

Code:

```
// hide all the steps and forms, then show the first one
$('.steps, .form').hide().eq(0).show().find('.form').eq(0).show();
// form radio change action, uses the values, adds that as "action" to the Next button
$('.form').on('change', 'input:radio', function () {
    $(this).parents('.steps').find('.formNext').data('action', $(this).val());
    $(this).parents('.steps').find('.action').text($(this).val());
});
// put some action on the Next button, using the action from the radio choice
// hide the form, show the one choosen
$('.formNext').click(function () {
    var nextForm = $(this).parents('.steps').data('nextstep');
    var action = $(this).data('action');
    if (action && action.length) {
        $(this).siblings('.form').find('.action').text(action + " is " + nextForm + " action");
        $('#' + nextForm).show().find('.form.' + action).show();
        $(this).parents('.steps').hide();
    };
});
// event handler for new Previous button on second form
$('.previous').click(function () {
    $(this).parents('.steps').hide().find('.form').hide();
    $(this).parents('.steps').prev().show();
});
```

Note that I added some classes in various places to make the code smaller/easier.

Comment: This is impressive code, I'm still trying to wrap my head around it. Thank you for taking the time to provide your answer.

Comment: It's not that hard if you just take each thing individually, consider how to make it simpler and the code more maintainable.  As in the other answers, when I end up with a case/switch statement, I always consider how/why I need that and if I should re-factor to methods/functions somehow. I will add another answer based upon your final answer choice so you see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Based upon your final choice, and the fiddle you created, here as a simple refactor to consider:

Add a class "steps" and one for each value to the next steps.  For example:

```
<div id="step1" class='steps initial'>
```

and also here:

```
<div id="step1-1" class="school steps">
<div id="step1-2" class="home steps">
...
```

The replace all the code in the chosen answer as well as your fiddle with this:

```
var val = $('input:radio[name=path]').val();
$('.steps.initial').slideUp();// class added to the initial one (see above)
$('.steps.' + val).slideDown();
```

See it here using your fiddle with commented changes:

http://jsfiddle.net/Cxfgj/9/